# Easier MVVM ViewModel RoutedUICommand usage?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, menu, command

I've combined Josh Smith's [Using RoutedCommands with a ViewModel in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28093/Using-RoutedCommands-with-a-ViewModel-in-WPF), vbfox's [Using CommandBindings in MVVM](http://blog.vbfox.net/post/2011/12/23/Using-CommandBindings-in-MVVM), and my own spin for specifying the RoutedUICommand Text and KeyGesture while declaring a CommandBinding in XAML.

Advantages:

- No need to explicitly reference ViewModel like Smith. He does:

```xml
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VMCommanding.ViewModel" 
...
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
  <jas:CommandSinkBinding 
    Command="vm:CommunityViewModel.KillAllMembersCommand" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

I am using the [MVVM Light Toolkit's](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) Locator class to indirectly get a ViewModel, so I don't want this. Also, since this is creating a normal CommandBinding under the hood, you can't use Bindings to specify the command (CommandBinding doesn't inherit from DependencyObject). vbfox gets around this by creating his own CommandBindings class.

- No need to create for a separate ICommand like vbfox. He does:

```xml
<f:Mvvm.CommandBindings>
  <f:MvvmCommandBindingCollection>
    <f:MvvmCommandBinding
      Command="f:MyRoutedCommands.SomeRoutedCommand"
      Target="{Binding MyCommandInViewModel}"
      CanExecuteChangedSuggestRequery="True" />
  </f:MvvmCommandBindingCollection>
</f:Mvvm.CommandBindings>
```

So you have to make a RoutedUICommand somewhere (in your View directory?), and an separate ICommand in your ViewModel.

Instead, I "only" have to implement ToggleReadComand in my ViewModel:

```cs
_commandSink.RegisterCommand(_toggleReadCommand, 
                             p => CanToggleRead, 
                             p => ToggleRead());
...
public static readonly RoutedUICommand _toggleReadCommand =
       new RoutedUICommand();
public static RoutedUICommand ToggleReadCommand
{
  get { return _toggleReadCommand; }
}

private bool CanToggleRead
{
  get { return Files.CurrentItem != null; }
}

private void ToggleRead()
{
  ToggleFileInfoFields(f => f.Read = !f.Read);
}
```

And I use it like this:

```xml
<cmd:Mvvm.CommandBindings>
  <cmd:MvvmCommandBindingCollection>
    <cmd:MvvmCommandBinding Command="{Binding ToggleReadCommand}" 
                            Gesture="Toggle _Read|Ctrl+R" />
  </cmd:MvvmCommandBindingCollection>
</cmd:Mvvm.CommandBindings>
...
<MenuItem Header="_View">
  <MenuItem Command="{Binding ToggleReadCommand}" />
</MenuItem>
```

I get all the advantages of using RoutedUICommands: the Command text is automatically displayed in my MenuItem along with the shortcut key (including disable support), my menu item UI (or any other control that binds to ToggleReadCommand) is specified in one place via XAML in my view (no more separate CommandBindings and InputBindings), but I still get to put my Command code in my ViewModels where it belongs.

Now here's my questions. First of all, I'd like to be able to do this (emulating how a normal Window.CommandBindings is declared):

```xml
<cmd:Mvvm.CommandBindings>
  <cmd:MvvmCommandBinding Command="{Binding ToggleReadCommand}" 
                          Gesture="Toggle _Read|Ctrl+R" />
</cmd:Mvvm.CommandBindings>
```

How can I avoid having to explicitly specify the MvvmCommandBindingCollection?

My Gesture support works, but I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error indication underneath `Gesture="Toggle _Read|Ctrl+R"` in the Visual Studio 2012 XAML editor? I added the following to vbfox's MvvmCodeBinding.cs:

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty GestureProperty = 
  DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Gesture",
    typeof(String),
    typeof(MvvmCommandBinding),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, OnGestureChanged));

static void OnGestureChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ((MvvmCommandBinding) d).OnGestureChanged((String) e.NewValue);
}

private string _gesture;
void OnGestureChanged(String newValue)
{
  _gesture = newValue;
  var command = _commandSinkBinding.Command as RoutedUICommand;
  if (command == null)
    return;

  CreateGesture(command, newValue);
}

private static void CreateGesture(RoutedUICommand command, string gestureStr)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(gestureStr) || command == null)
    return;

  var fields = gestureStr.Split(new char[] {'|'}, 2);
  if (fields.Length == 1)
    command.Text = gestureStr;
  else {
    command.Text = fields[0];
    var gesture = fields[1];
    var kgc = new KeyGestureConverter();
    var kg = kgc.ConvertFromString(gesture) as System.Windows.Input.KeyGesture;
    command.InputGestures.Add(kg);
  }
}

[Bindable(true)]
public String Gesture
{
  get { return (String) GetValue(GestureProperty); }
  set { SetValue(GestureProperty, value); }
}
```

(I also changed vbfox's `CommandBinding _commandBinding` to Smith's `CommandSinkBinding _commandSinkBinding`, and call CreateGesture() from OnCommandChanged() in case the Gesture is created before the Command). How can I get rid of the XAML editor error indication?

Finally, this is somewhat of a Frankenstein Monster. I'm sure there is all sorts of duplicate functionality. vbfox expressly says he came up with his code to avoid using Smith's VMCommanding. Plus I started off with using the MVVM Light Toolkit. My current stuff is just a "proof of concept" to show that my approach will work.

Does someone know if there is a better way to do all this that is already implemented somewhere? I want to be able to declare in XAML my RoutedUICommand (via Binding) in a single line that also sets the Text and Gesture (with no separate CommandBinding & InputBinding required). And I want the actual RoutedUICommands to be implemented in my ViewModel.

If not, I can probably eliminate lots of kruft by really looking closely at these three packages and doing some refactoring.

Comment: Did you ever pursue this further? I have been pondering a similar approach. On the other hand, part of me wants to get away from using RoutedUICommands altogether; however sometimes commands need to work with existing ApplicationCommands.

Comment: As stated, this question seems very broad. It would be helpful if you could edit it, to restate the _specific_ question you are looking for assistance with, but without requiring the lengthy background, but instead providing a good [mcve] that shows exactly what you've implemented, and also a clear explanation of what that code example does and how that's different from what you'd prefer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to simplify the way command bindings are implemented, so that you get the advantages of `RoutedUICommand` (input gesture and text display for command in e.g. menus, buttons, etc.), but still can declare the command _implementation_ in your view model instead of e.g. having to create a command binding that delegates execution of the command to the view model. I've been wrestling with the same issues and have some ideas, but it's not clear to me whether your issues really are the same as mine and so don't know whether answering here would be useful.